# Run individual test with debug logging in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My google foo is failing me: Is there a simple way to change the log level to `debug` when running just a single test in Rails (using line number suffix `rails test test/test_file.rb:15`) and keep it at `info` when running the entire suite via `rails test`?

I am using minitest (rather than Rspec).

Currently, I put the following at the top of the test when debugging a failure:

```rb
Rails.logger.level = 0 # Print at debug level
```

Comment: Not that I know of, but seems like a good candidate for a Minitest feature.